# How drop an audio stream using avconv?

Tags: avconv

How do I Drop audio from a MKV with DTS encoding? I am using this command `avconv -i Movie.mkv -c:v copy movie.mp4`.

I know the command would include the codec command but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like the option -an should do the trick.  Just ran a file, confirmed, new file had no sound.

```
-an (output)
   Disable audio recording.
```

from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html

Answer (score 6):

To my understanding the `-an` parameter will simply drop audio from the output. If thats not what you wanted, then you need to use the `-map` command and specify how individual streams from different sources should be mapped to the output. The following example takes only the first stream from the first file (usually video) and audio from the second file.

```
avconv -i input0.mkv -i input1.m4a -map 0:0 -c:v copy -map 1 -c:a copy output.mp4
```